# Line breaks while typing but can be fixed after with cap-J

Tags: line-breaks

My lines break when I am typing beyond a certain length in vim, but afterwards, if I move up one line and type <kbd>J</kbd>, the line will reconnect.

So it is apparently not a matter of fixed length. I would like the line not to break while typing. Is there a setting enabling this in `.vimrc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `:h 'textwidth'`:

> Maximum width of text that is being inserted.  A longer line will be
> broken after white space to get this width.  A zero value disables
> this.